# Android gui components from 4.x

Tags: android

I have an app for Android where in one screen, we have ToggleButton for 2.x and Switches for 4.x. I was able to create the layout folders for versions layout-v14 etc. and the layout xml's work fine.

My concern is from the coding standpoint, I want to be able to get the component (switch or togglebutton) from code and have it work from API 10 and later. However, the older API's do not have android.widget.switch. Is there any other work around? Otherwise I'll have to show a ToggleButton to all users :(

I treid to read the below for this:

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-tutorial/switches-example-in-android/

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. They both inherit from `CompoundButton`. So it's ok to import `android.widget.CompoundButton`. No need to import `ToggleButton` or `Switch`. Case closed.